# Vf component for different objects

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I want to design one vf component for 2 different sobjects with same fields

Answer (score 1):

You can reference fields by their name and so not be specific about the SObject type using this `[]` syntax:

```
<apex:component>

  <apex:attribute name="sob" type="SObject" description=""/>

  <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlock>
          <apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:inputField value="{! sob['FirstName'] }"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{! sob['LastName'] }"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

The page can then pass whatever SObject type it likes to the component:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

    <c:myComponent sob="{! Contact }"/>

    <!-- Needed to tell the standard controller what fields to query here. -->
    <!-- Fields could also be nominated in a custom controller. -->
    <apex:outputText value="{! Contact.FirstName }" rendered="false"/> 
    <apex:outputText value="{! Contact.LastName }" rendered="false"/> 

</apex:page>
```